# flutter listview skroll resets counter in text widget

Tags: flutter, dart, cubit

I had this test app part working.  it would update bagel counter but would update all the bagel counter on screen.   I moved my cubit build.provider to just the text field displaying count per item on screen.

This fix my global update to all bagel counts. so each now maintains own counter.   but now when i scroll off the screen, the counts are all reset.   I pull in the + 0 1  counter into listview as a class onto itself.

I have tried adding keys and
addAutomaticKeepAlives: true  but no luck.  fixing delete off scroll of counter 0 between +  -   being reset..

main.dart

```
    //TODO Screen Layouts
//TODO json pull and post
//TODO where to send post to email sms for store to see
//TODO Update live db with fields add to test dp  retailp and mobileactive
//TODO Create batch process to generate json file from db nightly or on demain via a button
//TODO TEST code
//TODO spining on load bagel icon or sprit - make.
//TODO total bagels / breads order
//TODO shopping card added
//TODO snackbar menu for as total add up pop up totals

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Services.dart';
import 'Product.dart';
import 'bagelcounter.dart';
import 'cubit/counter_state.dart';
import 'cubit/counter_cubit.dart';
import 'cubit/counter_cubit_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart'; //addded

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

// #docregion MyApp
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool keepAlive = true;    // not working 
  // #docregion build
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Startup Name Generator',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // Add the 3 lines from here...
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline1: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Corben',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            fontSize: 24,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ), // ... to here.
      home: buildJsonParseDemo(),

      // org      home: buildJsonParseDemo(),
    );
  }

  JsonParseDemo buildJsonParseDemo() => JsonParseDemo();
  // #enddocregion build
}

class JsonParseDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  //
  JsonParseDemo() : super();

  @override
  _JsonParseDemoState createState() => _JsonParseDemoState();
}

class _JsonParseDemoState extends State<JsonParseDemo> {
  //
  List<Product> _product;
  bool _loading;

//quick fix make this getter
//static //todo make live counter
  int mbakerdoz = 0;
  //get bakerdoz => mbakerdoz;

//static  //todo make live counter
  int singles = 10;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loading = true;
    Services.getUsers().then((product) {
      setState(() {
        _product = product;
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
  }
  //TODO find day of week to only see items available on day:
  //DateTime date = DateTime.now();
  //print("weekday is ${date.weekday}");
//TODO Add quantiy field of 1 - 6 , default 0 ,to bagel and breads

//TODO Bottom total of item and price.  Tax not included

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Bagels & Breads'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ListView.separated(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          addAutomaticKeepAlives: true, //not working to sotp skroll delete
          // key: UniqueKey(), key not fix update all.
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
            color: Colors.black,
            thickness: 2,
          ),
          itemCount: null == _product ? 0 : _product.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            Product product = _product[index];
            return ListTile(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              isThreeLine: true,
              // leading: Icon(Icons.plus_one),
              // trailing: Icon(Icons.exposure_minus_1),
              title: Text(product.pname,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blue[900],
                      fontSize: 22.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
              // product name

              subtitle: Text(
                   
                  '\$ ' +
                      (product.retailp.toStringAsFixed(2) +
                          '  each   index:' +
                          '$index  ' +
                          ' qty ' +
                          product.qty.toString()),
                          key: UniqueKey(),
                  style: TextStyle( 
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)
                      ),
            
              trailing: SizedBox(
                key: UniqueKey(),
                  width: 150,
                  child: BlocProvider<CounterCubit>(
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    create: (context) => CounterCubit(),
                    child: CounterCubitPage(),
                  )),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            //IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {}),
            Spacer(),
            Container(
              height: 55.0,
              width: 1.0,
            ),
            //TODO get bakerdoz and etotal on footer working need to pass data between main and bagelcounter

            Text("Baker's Dozen: $mbakerdoz " + "    Singles:  $singles",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),

            Spacer(),
            //IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {}),
            //IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert), onPressed: () {}),
          ],
        ),
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        color: Colors.lightBlue,
        notchMargin: 8.0,
      ),
      //floatingActionButton:
      //    FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {}),
      //floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
  }
}


counter_cubit_page.dart

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'counter_cubit.dart';
import 'counter_state.dart';

class CounterCubitPage extends StatelessWidget {
  // static const String routeName = '/counter_cubit';
  
  //@override
  //  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;  // not work
 // final bool keepAlive = true; // try to keep counter on skroll????

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    key: UniqueKey(),
        //appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Counter Cubit Bloc Double CTest')),
        body: BlocBuilder<CounterCubit, CounterCubitState>(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          builder: (context, state) => Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                key: UniqueKey(),
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    iconSize: 25,
                    onPressed: () => context.read<CounterCubit>().increment(),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '${state.totalbagels}', 
                    key: GlobalKey(), // not working 
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
               
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    iconSize: 25,
                    onPressed: () => context.read<CounterCubit>().decrement(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

I had tried    addAutomaticKeepAlives: true not working and try unique keys on fields ...

any pointers welcome.   I am new to flutter coding .. still lots to learn..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Oin.png)

Comment: Yeah, list views do that. but the solution to this is simply improving your state management. For example, you could create variables to store those counts so that the list view doesn't manage the states of the counts displayed but rather variables. i don't know if you get me?

Comment: Tonny I do thanks...

Comment: i found answer in using  
AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin  in my widget class for the cubit counter class..

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html